# Issue in latest version of Firefox

Tags: firefox

Initially, when my site loads some images are sliced off, which reappear after a few seconds. But once it scrolled the issue will reappear. It occurs in the latest version of Firefox only. It's fine in Firefox version 44, but I am getting the issue in 49 and 52.

The HTML structure is as follows.

```
 <div style="transform: translate(0px, 0px); position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
    <div class="whitecontent" style=" position: relative;">
      <p class="blockelemimage" style="position: absolute; top: -64px;">
        <img alt="Client Logo" src="">
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

there is issues about the transform-box and transform property in Firefox.
they are an experimental features  . [check here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Experimental_features) . and they are disabled in the beta versions.
also there are a reported bug [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1208550) about that.
 hope those links would help you.

Comment: Is there some other CSS fixes for this?